# DropDownList always selecting the wrong ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net

After making a selection and clicking a Save Button on my webpage, I always receive the `"0"` valued `ListItem`.  I expect to get whatever is selected instead of always getting the same thing.

My code is getting an array of resolutions from a video camera and putting them in the correct order and into the `DropDownList` (`ddlResolution`).

Main code:

```
//there is code above but ~should~ be irrelevant 
//selectedCam is a custom object.  its the video camera
if (selectedCam != null)
{
    //this will get an array of resolutions for this camera
    string[] res = selectedCam.GetValidResolutionsAsArray();
    ddlResolution.ClearSelection();
    ddlResolution.Items.Clear();

    //putt resolutions in correct order
    if (res.Length >= 3)
    {
        AddItem(ddlResolution, GetResolutionQualityString(1, res), "1");
        AddItem(ddlResolution, GetResolutionQualityString(0, res), "0");
        //ignore extra small resolutions...thats why we skip "2"
        //check to see if the last resolution a duplicate
        string hd = string.Format((string)GetLocalResourceObject("ResMedium"), res[3]);
        if (res.Length >= 4 && ddlResolution.Items.FindByText(hd) == null)
            AddItem(ddlResolution, GetResolutionQualityString(3, res), "3");
    }
    if (!resolutionSelected) SelectValue("0", ddlResolution);
}
```

Methods used in above code:

```
private static void AddItem(DropDownList ddl, string text, string value)
{
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(text, value));
}

//gets strings from a resource file
private string GetResolutionQualityString(int i, string[] res)
{
    if (res == null || res.Length <= 0) return "";
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0: return string.Format((string)GetLocalResourceObject("ResMedium"), res[i]);
        case 1: return string.Format((string)GetLocalResourceObject("ResLow"), res[i]);
        case 3: return string.Format((string)GetLocalResourceObject("ResHigh"), res[i]);
        default: return "";
    }
}

private void SelectValue(string value, ListControl rbList)
{
    foreach (ListItem li in rbList.Items)
        if (li.Value == value)
            li.Selected = true;
}
```

Code in the method for the Save Button:

```
log.Info("ddlResolution.SelectedValue = " + ddlResolution.SelectedValue);//TODO REMOVE
```

This gives the following no matter what I pick:

> 2014-07-02
>   17:54:25.049  7812    CLASSNAME   Information ddlResolution.SelectedValue =
>   0
>
> 2014-07-02
>   17:54:30.844  5556    CLASSNAME   Information ddlResolution.SelectedValue =
>   0
>
> 2014-07-02
>   17:54:35.008  7504    CLASSNAME   Information ddlResolution.SelectedValue =
>   0

Comment: The so-called `Main code` - where and how it is called?

Comment: Are you verifying that current load is not a postback?

Comment: @Andrei No. The drop down list should be updated postback or not.  Is there anything particular I need to do during a postback when changing a drop down list?

Comment: I was about to say "maintain selection cause it is being reset on every ddl binding", but then noticed `resolutionSelected` variable. Looks like some part of important code is actually left out. How do you initialize and use this variable?

Comment: @Andrei Sorry I forgot to mention about `resolutionSelected`.  Part of the code before will attempt to select the stored value from a database.  Also, I changed this `if (selectedCam != null)` to this `if (!IsPostBack && selectedCam != null)`.  It worked for the most part.  However, I don't quite understand why

Comment: Here is the trick. On each postback you actually resetting the whole state of the ddl (by clearing all items). And selection is a part of that state, thus it is lost. However if your ddl binding is always the same (on each postback) - you can do it once, and the list of items will be maintained by ASP.NET through postbacks, along with selection. So what you have done with `!IsPostBack` is effectively "load all items once, and then just use them on further postbacks". Does this make it clear?

Comment: @Andrei That makes sense.  I have another question, I have this in my ASPX `<dnwc:ButtonWithPermissionsChecker ... OnClick="btnSave_Click" ... />`.  This is the for the save button.  However, when I'm stepping through the debugger after clicking the save button, it goes to `Page_Load` before it goes to `btnSave_Click`.  I thought it would go directly to `btnSave_Click` for an `OnClick`?

Comment: That is how ASP.NET pages work. Search for something called "ASP.NET page life cycle", it would be quite hard to continue development without understanding it. Short answer is yes, this is right behavior, `Page_Load` is always called before control event handlers

Comment: @Andrei Please post that as an answer (your entire explanation).  It helped in solving my problem  |=^]